# Access default OpenLayers style

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a `ol.StyleFunction` set on a layer.

```
function style(feature: ol.Feature, resolution: number): ol.style.Style {
  return ol.style.Style({
    // stuff from the feature properties
  });
}
```

Not all of the features contain their own styling information.
In this case, i'd like to fall back to the default style.

```
function style(feature: ol.Feature, resolution: number): ol.style.Style {
  if (!hasOwnStyle(feature)) {
    // defaultStyle is private :(
    return ol.style.Style.defaultStyle();
  }
  return ol.style.Style({
    // stuff from the feature properties
  });
}
```

Is there a way to access the default style?

Comment: Did you  try `return feature.getStyle();`?????? It should be assigned if not provided.

Comment: @pavlos true, good idea!

Comment: `feature.getStyle()` is often `null`, so it is better to use `createDefaultStyles(feature, resolution)`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

A style function which returns the default style is assigned to newly created vector layers.  You can get the style array by running the function

```
var defaultStyles = new ol.layer.Vector().getStyleFunction()();
```

The editing style is a function which requires a feature with geometry

```
var defaultEditingStyleFunction = new ol.interaction.Select().getOverlay().getStyleFunction();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default style back

```
import style from 'ol/style';

var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
   color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
 });
 var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: '#3399CC',
   width: 1.25
 });
 var styles = [
   new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
       fill: fill,
       stroke: stroke,
       radius: 5
     }),
     fill: fill,
     stroke: stroke
   })
 ];
```

As showed in the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style-Style.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FeatureLike } from 'ol/Feature/'
import Style from 'ol/style/Style'
import { createDefaultStyle } from 'ol/style/Style'

function getStyles(feature: FeatureLike, resolution: number): Style[] {
  // return default styles (array)
  return createDefaultStyle(feature, resolution)
}

// or

function getStyle(feature: FeatureLike, resolution: number): Style {
  // return default style
  return createDefaultStyle(feature, resolution)[0]
}
```